# How to work only on ints in Python?

Tags: python, integer, equation

I have problem with my code. The task was to search for 3 integers that solves this equation 6*a+9*b+20*c = x, where x is an input. The problem is that my code only works for floats, and I unable to force it to give me an anwser only while a,b,c are integers.

Here's the code in Python:

```
def mc_nuggets(numWings):
    for Na in range(0, numWings + 1):
        for Nb in range(0, numWings - Na + 1):
            for Nc in range(0, numWings - Na - Nb + 1):
                num_a = (numWings -  9*Nb - 20*Nc)/6
                num_b = (numWings -  6*Na - 20*Nc)/9
                num_c = (numWings -  9*Nb - 6*Nc)/20
                if (6*num_a + 9*num_b + 20*num_c == numWings and type(num_a) is int == True and type(num_b) is int == True and type(num_c) is int == True):
                    return [num_a, num_b, num_c]
return [None, None, None]
```

Do u have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Indentation is incorrect

Comment: Are you doing this as part of MIT 6.00x?

Comment: is equation correct 6*a+9*b+20*b or it should be 6*a+9*b+20*c

Comment: Yes, it's 2nd problem set. 
Corrected the equation, thanks sundar

Comment: @moonit then bear this, from the Fall 2012 version, in mind: *"From the 6.00x course staff, please do not engage in this type of cheating. First off, this is a violation of the Honor Code. Secondly, the actions of the few of you engaging in this behavior puts a bad face on all edX staff and students. Please do not ask for homework help on Stack Overflow. Use our forums, and when our forums are closed, follow the Honor Code and do your own work."*

Comment: I am not an MIT student, just doing it for myself

Comment: I posted an answer but just for you, the `== True` are very redundant and should be removed since `if a == True:` is equivalent to `if a`.

Comment: You should change your checks from `type(num_x) is int == True` to `type(num_x) is int`.

The `==` is unnecessary, and the way you have it is evaluating as `type(num_x) is (int == True)` which is the same as `type(num_x) is False`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using python 2 or 3? On python 2, your code will truncate integer so it's incorrect.

On python 3, it is not because the value is `3.0` that the type is integer, it's float. To check if it's an integer value, use the `is_integer` method, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer.

Here is a method on how to make it without having to deal without float: You should iterate directly over a and b. Greater value for a is `numwings / 6` (when b and c are 0). Then you could iterate b until `(numwings - 6 * a) / 9`. Once you get there, you know that `20 * c = numwings - 6 * a - 9 * b` so you do not  need your third loop, and you can easily check if there is an integer such as the previous equation is correct (check with modulo for example).

Comment: Also it is possible t use // operator to stay in integer-only field.

Comment: @greatvovan Yes but if you use `//` operator you have the same problem than with python 2, your values are truncated. In this case it will only generated multiple solution with same value.

Comment: I'm about iteration borders, they should be integer anyway.

Comment: @greatvovan Yes you're right, I was just giving tips on how to do the exercice.

Answer (score 0):

my solution to the problem:

```
def mc_nuggets(numWings):
    for Na in range(0, numWings + 1):
        for Nb in range(0, numWings - Na + 1):
            for Nc in range(0, numWings - Na - Nb + 1):
                num_a = (numWings -  9*Nb - 20*Nc)
                num_b = (numWings -  6*Na - 20*Nc)
                num_c = (numWings -  9*Nb - 6*Na)
                if (num_a % 6 == 0 and num_b % 9 == 0 and num_c % 20 == 0):
                    if (num_a >= 0 and num_b >= 0 and num_c >= 0):
                        return [num_a/6, num_b/9, num_c/20]
     return [None, None, None]
```